# C# sockets cannot sent data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, stream

Hello guys this method sending file on client machine

```
        private void StartServer()
    {
        TcpListener lsn = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 27015);
        Socket sck;

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                lsn.Start();
                sck = lsn.AcceptSocket();
                byte[] b = new byte[100];
                int k = sck.Receive(b);
                string recived = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                {
                    recived = "" + recived + "" + Convert.ToChar(b[i]).ToString();
                }

                if (recived == "Version")
                {
                    string _ipPort = sck.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

                    var parts = _ipPort.Split(':');
                    _IPAddr = IPAddress.Parse(parts[0]);
                    _Port = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
                    sck.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1.1.0.0"));
                }

                k = sck.Receive(b);
                recived = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                {
                    recived = "" + recived + "" + Convert.ToChar(b[i]).ToString();
                }

                if (recived == "Update")
                {
                    fName = "Cannonball.mp3";

                    byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fName);
                    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Cannonball.mp3");
                    byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length);

                    clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length + fileData.Length];

                    fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                    fileName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                    fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileName.Length);

                    if (sck.Connected == true)
                    {
                        sck.Send(clientData);
                        sck.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When its goes to last if statment does not doing nothing. I wrote this code

```
Socket sck1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        sck1.Connect(_IPAddr, _Port);
                        sck1.Send(clientData);
```

but visual studio gives error that cannot establish connection. 
I tried 999 port which i knew was open `sck1.Connect(_IPAddr, 999);` and client recieved file.
Does anyone know how i can send file that remote endpoint(sck.RemoteEndPoint) which server got ?

Comment: What is this for? `recived = "" + recived + "" +`..., am I missing something or its the same as `recived +=`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sck1.Connect(_IPAddr, 999)` connects to *some* socket on the server's machine, then at least the value of `_IPAddr` is correct.

Did you check what value `_Port` has when you are trying to connect? Does it match the port number the server is listening at?

If these numbers match, you could try the following to test if your server is reachable:

- Start the server application
- On the client machine, open a browser and type: http://111.11.11.111:27015 (replace the 111's with the actual IP address)
- If the server accepts a socket at that time, the server is reachable and you'll need to focus on the client application rather than the server.

Comment: PS. What do you mean with "When its goes to last if statment does not doing nothing." if you can't even connect to the server yet?

Comment: i mean when if ends its goes on while loop. When client app sends "Update" tcp listener starting listen on _Port and im getting _Port like tihs :  string lep = sck.LocalEndPoint.ToString();
                var parts = lep.Split(':');
                _Port = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);

Comment: The code you posted requires two commands to be sent. The first command can be "Version", else it is ignored. After the "Version" part you have another `Receive`, blocking until the second command is received. If that second command is "Update" it will send data. The rest of your story is quite vague, and it seems like you are having multiple problems instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [TCPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) instead of Sockets.

EDIT: Since your having more than one problem here. I decided  to show you how I like to do something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading;

public static class Server
{
    private static Thread _listenThread;

    public static IPEndPoint ServerEp { get; set; }

    private static TcpListener _listener;

    // Listens for clients and creates a new thread to talk to each client on
    private static void ListenMain()
    {
        /* Start Lisening */

        _listener = new TcpListener(ServerEp);
        _listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient newClient = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            // Create a thread to handle client communication
            var clientThread = new Thread((ClientComm)) {IsBackground = true};



            clientThread.Start(newClient);
        }

    }

    // The Client Communcation Method
    private static void ClientComm(object clientobject)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient) clientobject;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = RecieveMessage(client);

                // process the message object as you see fit.
            }
            catch
            {
                if (!client.Connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // you could create a wrapper object for the connections
            // give each user a name or whatever and add the disconnect code here
        }
    }

    private static DataMessage RecieveMessage(TcpClient client)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        return (DataMessage)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    public static void SendMessage(DataMessage message, TcpClient client)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(client.GetStream(), message);
    }

    // Starts...
    // You could add paramaters to this if you need to I like to set with Server.Etc
    public static void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_listenThread.IsAlive) return;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            _listenThread = new Thread(ListenMain) { IsBackground = true };
        }

        _listenThread.Start();
    }
}

// Must be in both client and server in a shared .dll
// All properties must be serializable
[Serializable]
public class DataMessage
{
    public string StringProp{ get; set; }

    public int IntProp { get; set; }

    public bool BoolProp { get; set; }

    // will cause an exception on serialization. TcpClient isn't marked as serializable.
  /*   public TcpClient Client { get; set; } */
}
```

I'll post my client if you need me to. :)
Good Luck!

Comment: Post your TCPClient code here. And what your trying to do with it exactly.